# 2 part about Mustache for Java. Generating a table, appending image to end of email

Tags: java, mustache, jakarta-mail

I am trying to set up Mustache so that the email that is sent out will have a table of contents and also at the end of the email a logo.

I've tried to set up the table by passing it the html code:
ie:

```
<table><tr>...<td>...</td></tr></table>
```

When I receive the email, I see the actual text but not a rendered table.

Second part was how can I attach a logo to this email with Mustache?

I am using javax.mail with Mustache.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028670/how-to-set-mimebodypart-contenttype-to-text-html might help with the first part

Comment: @OsamaJaved ya ive set the content type to html/text -->             simpleMessage.setContent(template.getBody(), "text/html");