# JavaMail sent BitSarver file and not a pdf file

Tags: java, email, pdf, jakarta-mail

i have created a method to send a mail using java GUI with multi files attachments. When the method sends the mail  it's sent attachment files type like microsoft office and pdf to the receiving mail as BitSarver. I need to file to send as there type so other automatic system can work by reading the attachment file and print it.

this is the method.

```
    static public boolean sendMail(String to,String subject,String text_filed)
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port ","465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("eamil", pass);
                }
            }
    );
    try 
    {
        Message m = new MimeMessage(session);
        m.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userMAil));

        System.out.println("from "+userMAil);

        m.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

        System.out.println("to "+to);

        m.setSubject(subject);

        System.out.println("the subject "+subject);

        MimeBodyPart bodypart = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodypart.setText(text_filed);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(bodypart);

        System.out.println("the content "+text_filed);
        for(int i = 0;i< main_controller.attachments_path.size();i++)
        {   
            bodypart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(main_controller.attachments_path.get(i));
            System.out.println("the file location"+main_controller.attachments_path.get(i));
            bodypart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            //bodypart.setFileName(main_controller.filesFrame.getFilename());

            System.out.println("the file name"+main_controller.filesFrame.getFilename());
            multipart.addBodyPart(bodypart);
        }


        m.setContent(multipart);
        //m.setText(text_filed);

        Transport.send(m);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done!");
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String m = e.getMessage();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.println(m);
        return false;
    }
}
```

hope you can help me :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem could be related to this:

[How to set MimeBodyPart ContentType to "text/html"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028670/how-to-set-mimebodypart-contenttype-to-text-html)

Try to call MimeMessage.saveChanges() before submission to get the content type populated properly from the DataHandlers.

Comment: i tried but i still gets the same result
`m.saveChanges();
m.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(m);`

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail, via the JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF), picks the MIME type based on the filename extension.  The list of "known" filename extensions is relatively small.  You can add to it as described in the [MimetypesFileTypeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) javadocs.  Or, you can use the [MimeBodyPart.attachFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method and specify the MIME type directly.

Oh, and you'll want to clean up these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean I'll attach the files into email
can yoe be more specific.

Comment: You read all the links I provided, right?  Which part confused you?